# How do I relate two table to know which value is included in ManyToMany field in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Hope that the title is not as confusing as I thought it would be. I currently have a table for **PaymentsData**:

```
class PaymentsData(models.Model):
   match = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   amount = models.DecimalField(default = 0, max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2)
   players = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True)
   playerspaid = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='paid', blank=True)
   datespent = models.DateField('Date Spent')

def __str__(self):
    return self.match
```

This field is used to create matches and include the number of players that played within players section and when they paid move them to **playerspaid** field.
What I wanted to do is using a different table, I wanted to present all the players individually, and include the **matches** that they need to pay for (which we can know by fetching the **players** in **PaymentsData** above). So it should look something similar to this:

```
class PlayersPaymentDetails(models.Model):
    player = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    matches = models.ManyToManyField(PaymentsData, blank=True)
    amountdue = models.DecimalField(default = 0, max_digits=5, decimal_places = 2)
```

here in the matches, it should show all the matches that the player is selected in the players field within **PaymentsData** and the **amountdue** should show how much the player owes all together.

I have tried customising the model using the **save()** method, however when the **players** gets unselected from the **PaymentsData**, it does not change the **PlayersPaymentDetails** table.

Hope someone can help, Thanks. Do let me know if that's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need another table?
You can get the matches like so:

```
player = Profile.objects.get(...) # get the player you want
matches = player.paymentsdata_set.all()
```

and `amountdue`:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

player = Profile.objects.get(...) # get the player you want
amountdue = player.paymentsdata_set.all().aggregate(amountdue=Sum('amountdue'))['amountdue']
```

Comment: I could do that, however I wanted to show that on the admin page, do you think there is any way I can display this information without creating another table. As the admin will be using the admin page to apply players to matches and see who is left to pay.